# How to develop a jQuery plugin with dart

Tags: jquery, dart

I have some issues with my jQuery plugin (a basic [monthpicker](https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/Simple-MonthPicker))

I want to rewrite most of it in Dart.

But I'm new to Dart and I'm looking for more infos :

- Objectively, is Dart a good option for this kind of projects ?
- How to proceed ?

For this second point I have some clues but not sure :

1. I develop a main class with Dart
2. Compile it to javascript
3. plug it to `$.fn.myStuff`

Is it the right process ?

Any feedback on jQuery plugins development is welcome.

Comment: I can bet Dart is not Dead, but too young for what I want. I will have a look to Typescript, I think it can be a good fit for my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not a good scenario for Dart. The Dart team is working on a transpiler ([dev_compiler](https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler)) that produces JS that can easily reused in JS projects. Currently its just experimental and it's capabilities are limited.

The default dart2js output is minimized and treeshaken JS that works only well when the whole application is built to JS at once.

Comment: I don't mark it the accepted answer because I hope there will be a good option for this one day (maybe dev_compiler)

Comment: As you like, but you can also make any other (new or not) answer the accepted one at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I try to update my answer in time when new options emerge so you don't have any additional work :)